# Trailing dots in a list over 2 lines

Tags: css, list

Using this site and others, I have created a working list that includes trailing dots.  When everything is on a single line, it works exactly like I want.  When the left hand text spans 2 lines it works as I expect.

What I'm stuck on is that when the list spans 2 lines because of the right text, the background is not the styled background I have.  Rather, it is defaulting to the page background for the beginning part of that second line.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="upcoming">
<ul class=longleaders>
    <p>Upcoming Events</p>
    <li><span>APRA Annual International Conference - Las Vegas, NV</span>
        <span>July 30 – August 2, 2014</span>

    <li><span>aasp Summit 2014 And May the Forth be with you and you and you - Chicago, IL</span>
        <span>October 20-22, 2014</span>

    <li><span>Crazy Event/2015</span>
      <span>March 11-12, 2015</span>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#upcoming p {
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f04e37;
    padding-left: 0.1rem;}
ul.longleaders {
    max-width: 35em; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000;}
ul.longleaders li:after {
    float: left; 
    width: 0; 
    white-space: 
    nowrap; 
    content:
    ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
    ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
    ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
    ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "}
ul.longleaders li {
    clear: both}
ul.longleaders span:first-child {
    padding-right: 0.33em;}
ul.longleaders span + span {
    float: right; 
    padding-left: 0.33em; 
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 1}

#upcoming li {
    padding: .1rem;
    color: #fff;
    clear: both;}
    #upcoming li:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #a9cf37;}
        #upcoming li:nth-child(even) span + span {
            background: #a9cf37;}
        #upcoming li:nth-child(even) span:first-child {
            background: #a9cf37;}
    #upcoming li:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #71513a;}
        #upcoming li:nth-child(odd) span + span {
            background: #71513a;}
        #upcoming li:nth-child(odd) span:first-child {
            background: #71513a;}
```

I'm stumped.  I think I have to add something (like a `:before`) to the `span + span` but I'm not seeing it.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like today.  The goal is to get the white area in that first line to be green, the white area in the second line to be brown, and so on. http://goo.gl/YbrtTc

Here is a zip file with the HTML5 Boilerplate files I used to create this: http://goo.gl/htdDVo

Any ideas?

Comment: Any screenshot to help us to imagine what you want to do ?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. List items <li> must be closed.

Comment: @Diodeus No. *"The end tag can be omitted if it is immediately followed by another `<li>` element or if there is no more content in its parent element."* [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)